# Pointer declaration order matters?

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I wonder why the code from exercise 8.3 in **C : From Theory to Practice by G.S. Tselikis** works, although it shouldn't.

```
int main() {
  double *ptr, i;
  scanf("%lf", ptr);
  printf("Val = %f\n", *ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

However, a small change in the variable declaration leads to the expected behaviour (because `ptr` is not initialized).

```
int main() {
  double i, *ptr;
  scanf("%lf", ptr);
  printf("Val = %f\n", *ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Code Studio and clang (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)). Any ideas?

Comment: Neither of these "works".  `ptr` is not initialized in either of these examples.  Are you sure you are quoting the correct code from an actual book, and it's not from a chapter about _undefined behavior_?

Comment: `However, a small change in the variable declaration leads to the expected behaviour` I wonder what behavior you specifically expect when invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: By "the expected behaviour" do you mean a crash? A crash is not guaranteed, it depends on what you break.

Comment: The expected behaviour is a segmentation fault. Or at least some random data printed (read from `*ptr`).

> Neither of these "works".
Well with clang the first one does: it reads a number from the console and prints it back correctly. I agree with you that it shouldn't.

Comment: When behaviour is undefined, you can't expect any particular manifestation of the trouble — what you get is undefined, after all.  It can even appear to work.  If the value in the uninitialized variable `ptr` happens to be an address that can be written to without interfering with other operations, then it may seem to work.  But the fact that the pointer is uninitialized means that all bets about the behaviour are off.  You must avoid undefined behaviour precisely because you cannot know what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Both programs have undefined behavior because you pass an invalid address to `scanf()` to read the numeric value: `ptr` is not initialized.

If you properly set `ptr` to point to `i`, both will behave the same, but the second program can be written more directly with an initializer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  double *ptr, i;
  if (scanf("%lf", ptr = &i) == 1)
      printf("Val = %f\n", *ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

vs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  double i, *ptr = &i;
  if (scanf("%lf", ptr) == 1)
      printf("Val = %f\n", *ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any implementation detail of clang that may explain why the undefined behaviour of `double *ptr, i;`is different from `double i, *ptr;`?

Comment: It is quite vain to try and find an explanation for undefined behavior. Loading both functions in [godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/b5vPf9o8f) allows one to analyse the code generated for various compilers and compiler options. With `clang -O2`, the order of definitions makes no difference.